# How to read complex JSON in Android

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

If I have this string:

> anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{sequence=anyType{element=anyType{}; element=anyType{simpleType=anyType{restriction=anyType{maxLength=anyType{}; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; }; diffgram=anyType{DocumentElement=anyType{mytable=anyType{USER_ID=83; PROJECT_BY_DETAILS=An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film; }; mytable=anyType{USER_ID=88; PROJECT_BY_DETAILS=Test - over ye mountain blue ; }; }; }; }

How can I display it in an Android list view?

The expected output is:

```
USER_ID=83
PROJECT_BY_DETAILS=An adaptation of a nursery rhyme into a dramatic film

USER_ID=88
PROJECT_BY_DETAILS=Test - over ye mountain blue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String [] out;
Int i = 0;
//String result is your output (the code part from your question)
While(Result.indexOf("USER_ID") != -1){
Result = Result.substring(Result.indexOf ("USER_ID"),Result.length());
out[i] =  Result.substring(0,Result.indexOf(";");
Result = Result.substring(Result.indexOf (";"), Result.length());
i++;
}
//out [] is your array with the data you want to have
```

And with the array you can put the data in a listview.
Hope this helps :)